Get 404 error when refreshing a page in Angular 19 and ng serve
I'm building an application that have a login page, the angular version I use is Angular 19, and I run my app through ng serve.
When I access the link http://localhost:4200/ from my browser, I being redirect to http://localhost:4200/login and the page successfully display my login component. But when I refresh the page or type link http://localhost:4200/login directly to the browser, I get a 404 error, which display a message Cannot GET /login on the page.
I setup my routing in this way in my main.ts file:
import { enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './app/login/login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, title: 'Login' }
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        HttpClientModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CommonModule
      )
    ]
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
});

and my app.component.html look like this:
<!-- Basic structure might include a navigation bar and footer -->
<nav>
  <!-- Navigation links or menu here -->
  <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
  <!-- More links as needed -->
</nav>

<!-- Router Outlet to render routed components -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<footer>
  <!-- Footer content here -->
  <p>© 2024 Online Shopping App</p>
</footer>

Here is my app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, RouterOutlet, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true, 
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'online-shopping-app';
}


I have try to add a standalone property in my login component as some answer suggessted in other resources, but it doesn't help much. I also have try to check my base link in my index.html, but I ensure that the base link is set as <base href="/">. There are also other answer suggested that I should use hash strategy but I figure out that ng serve should have take care of that issue and only when I use other server I need to take care of that.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.css'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  })

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  onSubmit() {
    
    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      const email = this.loginForm.value.email;
      const password = this.loginForm.value.password;

      if(email && password){
        this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            console.log('Login successful', data);
            this.router.navigate(['/user-home']); // navigate to home on success
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.error('Login failed', error);
            // handle login failure, such as displaying an error message to the user
          },
          complete: () => console.log('Login request completed') // optional
        });
      }else {
        console.error('Form is not complete. Missing email or password.');
        // Optionally handle the case where email or password is missing
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid form submission');
      // Handle invalid form submission
    }
  }
}



How do you run your app ? Why do you rely on document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' ?

I often had the same Issue on my server if I didnt have a .htaccess in my application.
